# How to get selected user name in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am creating a custom listview item with a textview and a check box. Whenever the checkbox of corresponding to a user is selected, I would like to see his name in a toast. I have used the following code :

```
mUserList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(ManualInviteActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Users1 user = (Users1) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(user.isSelected()==true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't see anything however, when I toggle the check box. What is the mistake here ?
Thanks
(isSelected and getName are my own functions in the user class)

Adapter Code :

```
public class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Users1> {

    static Context context;
    static int layoutResourceId;
    Users1 data[] = null;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Users1[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        CheckBox cbxUser;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            holder.cbxUser = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.user_checked);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Users1 weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.cbxUser.setChecked(weather.isSelected());
        // holder.txtTitle2.setText(weather.title2);
        // holder.txtTitle2.setText(weather.title2);
        // holder.txtTitle3.setText(weather.title3);
        return row;
    }

}
```

Users1 class :

```
public class Users1 {

    public String title;
    boolean selected = true;

    public Users1()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Users1(String title,boolean selected) {
        super();
        this.selected = selected;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
     return title;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
     this.title = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
     return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
     this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are unable to check inside the list item. set focusable="false" in the <checkBox attribute.

Comment: instead of itemClickListener. Use checkChangedListener of checkbox inside adapter class .

Comment: was this problem solved? the use of a listview here makes things more difficult unless you access the checkbox globally as anyway if you want to use it independently, it should not depend on the "getView()" method of the listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to use onCheckedStateChange for Check box.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how exactly to do this ?I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: The checkbox is inside the list item. So how can I use this function directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a listener to your RadioGroup (not to your list).
Something like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    OnCheckedChangeListener OCCL = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                //...
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                //...
                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                //...
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(OCCL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        holder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    public class Customadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> names;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Customadapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
        this.context = context;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView name;
        CheckBox check;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final Holder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder=new Holder();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox,null);
            holder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.check.setId(position);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context,""+names.get(holder.check.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this part of the list adapter code or do i put this in the list item listener ?

Comment: this is part of list adapter

Comment: See my updated question. I have used a custom class to assign data to the adapter, not an arraylist itself. How do incorporate your code into this ? Also, why have you assigned the position to the textview when it should be the name ? Thanks

Comment: I didn't assign any position to textview I just displaying and if you want checkbox position you should do setid to checkbox

Comment: Okay and how do i assign data to the adapter using my own Users1 class rather than an arraylist like you have shown ?